# How to find this sum: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H^{(r)}(n)}{2^n n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am learning new sums and I would appreciate your hints about how to approach the following $$S(r)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H^{(r)}(n)}{2^n n}$$
where $$H^{(r)}(n)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{j^r}$$ is the harmonic number of order $r$.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: How is $H^{(r)}(n)$ defined in the above?

Comment: @ClementC. I just defined it properly. Many thanks for the hint.

Comment: There is still a typo -- it should be $1/j^r$, not $1/n^r$.

Comment: You find some closed form values (e.g. for $r=1,2,3)\;$ and more in terms of Riemann $\zeta$ and polylogarithms $\mathrm{Li}_k$ on http://www.pi314.net/eng/hypergse13.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach (I wrote this quickly, there may be typos or computation errors):

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H^{(r)}(n)}{2^n n}
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^n n k^r}
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n n k^r}
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{ k^r}\sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n n}
$$
Now, for $\lvert x\rvert < 1$
$$
\sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} = \int_0^x \frac{t^{k-1}}{1-t} dt
$$
so that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H^{(r)}(n)}{2^n n} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{ k^r}\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{t^{k-1}}{1-t} dt
= \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{1-t} \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{t^{k-1}}{k^r} \right) dt
$$
where all the swappings sum-integrals are legit "because everything is fine within the radius of convergence of power series." It remains to compute the last sum and integrate -- not sure it is obvious, but that's what I'd try.

Comment: I think the integration is hard to calculate, because the sum in the integral is represented by [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Comment: On the other hand, is a result expressed in terms of this function considered as closed-form? I'm not entirely sure what is the OP is looking for.

Comment: @ClementC. This is great, and is what I was looking for. Many thanks. The evaluation of the integral could be hard but doable, hence I am happy with your solution.